# Wordpress Divi Custom CSS on HTML Form

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and I am customising it with the Divi theme. I have added an HTML form to a 'Code' module and it works great. However I cannot work out where I should put the CSS. I have tried to 'Custom CSS' areas of both the row and module itself. Perhaps there is something wrong in the code? I have pasted it below. Thanks!

```css
input[type=text], select {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 12px 20px;
      margin: 8px 0;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    input[type=number], select {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 12px 20px;
      margin: 8px 0;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    input[type=submit] {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      padding: 14px 20px;
      margin: 8px 0;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    input[type=submit]:hover {
      background-color: #45a049;
    }
    
    div {
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      padding: 20px;
    }
```

```html
    <font face="helvetica"
    
    <META HTTPS-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
    <!-- NOTE: Please add the following <FORM> element to your page. -->
    <!-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
    <form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" target='_parent'>
    
    <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D0Y0000034cvq">
    <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="https://globalstudyuk.com/success-qatar">
    
    <!-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
    <!-- NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment -->
    <!-- these lines if you wish to test in debug mode. -->
    <!-- <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1> -->
    <!-- <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail" -->
    <!-- value="kasper.martlev@weare4c.com"> -->
    <!-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
    
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>   <input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" required=true/><br><br>
    
    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>   <input id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" required=true /><br><br>
    
    Date of Birth:  <span class="dateInput dateOnlyInput"> <input id="00N0Y00000RWiNa" name="00N0Y00000RWiNa" size="12" type="text" name="inputBox" placeholder=" DD/MM/YYYY" /></span><br><br>
    
    <label for="mobile">Mobile</label>   <input id="mobile" maxlength="40" name="mobile" size="20" type="number" pattern="\d*" required=true/><br><br>
    
    <label for="email">Email</label>   <input id="email" pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" required=true /><br><br>
    
    Current/Previous School/University:   <input id="00N0Y00000RWiNZ" maxlength="100" name="00N0Y00000RWiNZ" size="20" type="text" required=true /><br><br>
    
    Course you would like to study:   <input id="00N0Y00000RWiNi" maxlength="255" name="00N0Y00000RWiNi" size="20" type="text" required=true /><br><br>
    
    <label for="lead_source">Where did you hear about us?</label>   <select id="lead_source" name="lead_source"><option value="">--None--</option>
    <option value="Instagram">Instagram</option>
    <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
    <option value="Twitter">Twitter</option>
    <option value="Google">Google</option>
    <option value="British Council">British Council</option>
    <option value="Career day">Career day</option>
    <option value="Deferred">Deferred</option>
    <option value="Flier / Poster">Flier or Poster</option>
    <option value="GSUK Alumni">GSUK Alumni</option>
    <option value="GSUK_Website">GSUK_Website</option>
    <option value="Other_(Please specify)">Other</option>
    <option value="Referral_(Please specify)">Referral</option>
    <option value="School Counsellor_(Please specify)">School Counsellor</option>
    <option value="School Presentation">School Presentation</option>
    <option value="School Tour">School Tour</option>
    <option value="University Website_(Please specify)">University Website</option>
    <option value="Web">Web</option>
    </select><br><br>
    
    <input type=hidden id="00N0Y00000RWvPA" name="00N0Y00000RWvPA" type="checkbox" value="1" />
    
    <input type=hidden id="country_code" name="country_code"value="QA" />
    
    <input type=hidden id="city" name="city" value="Doha" />
    
    <center><input type="submit" name="submit"></center>
    
    
    
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

login to your dashboard -> click on Appearance -> click Customize -> click on Additional CSS and paste your css in that.

[image]

Comment: If you will add this CSS in customizer then it will apply on full site. It can conflict with other forms Its not the correct way. It can be included by using shortcode for specific page or any other way

Comment: @Ravi Kumar but he never mention that the css is for specific page and not all pages. even if he wants it to effect specific page then he can give a main class and use that class to target the form elements

Comment: Hi, I'd like it to apply to only one form. However, I will see what happens when I add it there.

Comment: @James Ellis you can give a main class to the form or the row and use that class to target the form elements

Answer (score 0):

We resolved the issue by removing

```
div {
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      padding: 20px;
    }
```

Although this would work fine on most pages, it was causing white boxes to appear in strange places, presumably due to the CMS we were using building pages in columns.